# How to handle error on multiple chained Observable in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin, RxJava, and Retrofit.
I want to send Http Request to the server.

1. PUT - update option of job
2. POST - run the job

After the first request success, then I send a second request.
So I used concatMap.

```
val updateJob = restService.updateJob(token, job.id, options) // PUT
val runJob = restService.runJob(token, job.id) // POST

updateJob.concatMap { runJob }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ job ->
        Log.d(TAG, "runJob - success: $job")
    }, {
        Log.e(TAG, "runJob - failed: ${it.message}")
        it.printStackTrace()
    })
```

What I want is to cancel, if the first request is failed.
How should I do this?

Here is a possible code.
But... this code is... I think this is ugly...
Is there any cool code, please?

```
disposable.add(
            restService.updateJob(token, job.id, options)    // PUT
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ job ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "updateJob - success")
                    restService.runJob(token, job.id)    // POST
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe({ job ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "runJob - success")
                        }, {
                            Log.e(TAG, "runJob - failed: ${it.message}")
                            it.printStackTrace()
                        })
                }, {
                    Log.e(TAG, "updateJob - failed: ${it.message}")
                    it.printStackTrace()
                })
        )
```

---

I have one more question.
I have the job list.
And I want to do the same thing.
Even if some jobs fail, I want to continue with the next jobs.
I considered "onErrorResumeNext, onErrorReturn, doOnError".
But they are not the solution.
How can I do this?

```
Observable.fromIterable(jobs)
            .concatMap { job ->
                val updateJob = restService.updateJob(token, job.id, options)
                val printJob = restService.printJob(token, job.id)

                updateJob.concatMap { printJob }
            }
            .window(1)    // I thought "window" can be the solution. But it doesn't work.
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ job ->
                Log.d(TAG, "runJobs - success")

            }, {
                Log.e(TAG, "runJobs - failed: ${it.message}")
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
```

Comment: please check the answer for your second question.
And please put the new question as another StackOverflow question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have already given the answer.
Your first case is correct

```
val updateJob = restService.updateJob(token, job.id, options) // PUT
val runJob = restService.runJob(token, job.id) // POST

updateJob.concatMap { runJob }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ job ->
        Log.d(TAG, "runJob - success: $job")
    }, {
        Log.e(TAG, "runJob - failed: ${it.message}")
        it.printStackTrace()
    })
```

So in this case, if `updateJob` request gets failed then the stream will move into `error stream` and `runJob` request will never be called.

`runJob` will be called only when `updateJob` is successful.

And after `updateJob` success if `runJob` fails, then also `error stream` will be called.

There is no need for your second solution.

And for your second question `onErrorResumeNext` should work. Return any dummy value and handle it in the `onNext`

```
Observable.fromIterable(jobs)
                    .concatMap { job -> restService.updateJob(token, job.id, options).onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.just(/*Send any dummy value*/)) }
                    .contcatMap { job -> restService.printJob(token, job.id).onErrorResumeNext{Flowable.just(/*Send any dummy value*/)} }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({ job ->
                        /*If dummy value received....handle it gracefully*/
                        Log.d(TAG, "runJobs - success")

                    }, {
                        Log.e(TAG, "runJobs - failed: ${it.message}")
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    })
```

Comment: Oh... Thank you :) I am the newbie.. It's not easy for me.

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Comment: I added a question, could you help me again, please?

Comment: @yoonhok please check the answer

Comment: Hmm... it is not the solution. it is not what I want.
I make a question newly for the second question, could you check it again, please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439986/how-to-continue-the-stream-with-error-in-rx